# Pre-processing - Removing outliers

Tags: preprocessing, outlier

I have two files, a training data with a label field and a test data without the label field. I have plotted a field "A" in train data:

[image]

It looks like outliers are 4,5,6 and should be removed.

Now plotting the field "A" in test file also shows somewhat similar results to the image shown. In that case, should I consider 4,5,6 as outliers, and remove them from train data, or keep them? Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In general, its **not** acceptable to drop an observation just because it is an outlier.

Sometimes outliers give us very important information about data. 
Removing outliers is legitimate if:

- it is obvious that's incorrect data
- not change the results and assumptions.

How to handle outliers? Try **other models** or use **data transformation**.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on "other models" or "data transformation"? May be you could provide a link to some tutorials? I am not familiar with any of them

Comment: About "other models"- it depends on your data and assumptions, I can't answer without more details.
"data transformation"- try for example log transformation, sample have you in this link:
https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/preprocessing_structured_data/handling_outliers/

Comment: I do not agree. It could be ok depending on the case. If you are interested in predicting a limited range in the case of a regression, you will achieve best results by dropping outliers (observations out of the range).

Comment: Rusoiba, outliers sometimes they are the most important data of all, how do you justify removing most valuable data from the dataset?

Comment: If I drop them from my training data, then will similar points in the test files be correctly labeled? Is there a general best practice, when one has such data in both test and train files?

Comment: No, you have to do it manually. No general rule, you should try a lot of options and find the best.